# Using grep to get the count of files where keyword exist

Tags: unix

i am trying to get the count of files which has matching keywords in directory. Code i used is:

```
grep -r -i --include=\*.sas 'keyword'
```

Can any one help me to, how to get the count of the files which contains the keyword.

Thanks

Comment: In which way does the code you used not work?

Comment: use some quote when using a *

Comment: @Armali This code give the number of times keyword occurs, the output i want is to display unique number of file having this keyword

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do two things. The first is to suppress normal output from grep and print only the file name with -l. The second is to pipe the output through to wc -l to get the count of the lines, hence the count of the files.

```
grep -ril "keyword" --include="*.sas" * | wc -l
```

Comment: But the number of lines in one file can be more than one if that keyword occurs more than one time, in that scenario would it work ?

Comment: If there is multiple instances of a search term in a file, -l will force grep to print the file name only once,